# Change calendar first day to specific day of week

Tags: google-calendar

My work week starts on Tuesday and I wanted to make google calendar meet my work rythm. Do you know how to change calendar first day to specific day of week ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you've already discovered, Google Calendar only offers Saturday, Sunday, and Monday as days to start the week.

I can't imagine that a client-side script could fix this. Your only option then would be to use a third-party calendar that does offer this feature and syncs with your Google Calendar.

If you want to let Google know that this is a feature you'd really like to have, use the "Send Feedback" tool in the gear menu.

Comment: Thanks ! I will contact them and give them my feedback as far as I don't know any third-party calendar that does offer this feature and syncs with your Google Calendar

Comment: We have a sister site ([softwarerecs.se]) where you might ask where to find one. Be sure to read the guidance there before posting, since they have some pretty stringent guidelines for questions.